# NodeJS fs Stats.isFile() not defined

Tags: node.js, filesystems, undefined, typeerror, fs

I'm new to NodeJS and I#m trying to read a directory recursively this is my code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readDir = function (dir, calback) {
fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);

    for (var file in files) {
        fs.stat(dir + "/" + file, function (err, stats) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);

            if (stats.isFile()) {
                calback(dir + "/" + file);
            }
            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                walk(file, calback);

            }
        });
    }
});
};
```

This is my ErrorMessage

```
C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\Enide-Studio-05-kepler-win32\ws\PlayerTest\hello-world-server.js:24
            if (fs.stats.isFile()) {
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'isFile' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\Enide-Studio-05-kepler-win32\ws\PlayerTest\hello-world-server.js:24:30
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

What is my mistake??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not exiting your function after encountering an error.

```
 fs.stat(dir + "/" + file, function (err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return; // exit here since stats will be undefined
        }

        if (stats.isFile()) {
            calback(dir + "/" + file);
        }
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            walk(file, calback);

        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. One could also write `return console.log()` as well, since returning nothing is functionally equivalent to `return undefined` and the result of console.log is `undefined`. I would also add that some consider it a good practice to `return callback(...)` as well. It sometimes save the need of an else block, etc.